# Were all the Jews enslaved in Egypt?

Tags: midrash, shemot-exodus, yetzias-mitzrayim

According to [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.14.3?lang=bi) Midrash there were Jews and

> They had favored positions among the Egyptians and could not dream of giving up their wealth. Therefore, they died in the plague of darkness.

([Translation Here](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/70397?lang=bi))

Do we have any background information about the fact that this midrash says that there were Jews in favored positions? Are we led to believe that there were Jews that were not enslaved? Or perhaps they developed these positions over the period of the 10 plagues? Or perhaps they weren't wealthy and the midrash is metaphorical and it means they lived "as if" they were wealthy, meaning they had gotten comfortable in Egypt and didn't desire to be redeemed?

Comment: The Leviim weren't enslaved, as Rashi points out

Comment: Moses wasn't enslaved.

Comment: @turkhill yes. He was a levite and had unique circumstances because of his upbringing being his Pharoah's house. The question was more geared towards a large segment of Jews seemingly living an emancipated lifestyle

Comment: I recall that the tribe of Levi was not enslaved and were allowed to continue with their priestly lifestyle because the Egyptians were respectful to other nation's priests. Also the Bnei Yosef didn't get enslaved , in fact I heard that they were given high positions some were even allowed to settle in E"Y, as in Divrei Yamim it mentions one of Yosef's descendants going down from E"Y to search for his cattle or sheep, can't exactly remember where it said this and what the exact details were.

Comment: @kapinkrunch I have never heard that. It's kind of interesting that  the bnei ephraim were the ones that were trying to make an early exit given that information. If you can I'd love to see the source!

Comment: ok I was refering to 1 Chronicles 7:20-24. And the Gath mentioned here is not Gath that is in the south near Gaza, it's a different Gath that's located in northern Canaan, as mentioned in Daat Mikra.               Also Rabbeinu Yehuda haChasid (17th century) said "Israel received many possessions from their forefathers  in the Land of Canaan. Even though they were in Egypt they were wont to send emissaries to Canaan to prepare fields and vine yards of their own. The descendants of Joseph, apparently of Efraim, built cities for themselves  in Canaan in the area of their future inheritances..."

Comment: @kapinkrunch that's interesting, been theres a [midrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Shimon_Bar_Yochai.13.16) that takes a whole different approach to that situation. Where God takes the Jews around the land of the philistines to avoid the ruins of the Bnei Ephraim who made their own calculation regarding when the Egyptian servitude was supposed to last and ended up in a bloody battle with the Philistines killing 300,000 which is vastly different then yehuda hachassid

Answer (score 2):

Although Meir's [response](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114688/13811) is more on the mark in answering your question based on the Midrash  itself, another consideration is the [Meshech Chochma (Vaera 8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Meshech_Hochma%2C_Vaera.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who says

> ויצום אל בני ישראל ואל פרעה כו' להוציא את בנ"י כו' יתכן כי גם אז
>   במצרים היו גדולי האומה אשר היו שרים נכבדים ואפרתים והם היו משעבדים את
>   בני ישראל לעבדים שמכרו המצרים להם ואולי היו המה השלשה שבטים ראובן
>   ושמעון ולוי שהנהיגו שררה במצרים כמו שאיתא במדרש נשא פ' י"ג לוי שלא היה
>   בשעבוד מצרים לכן לא נטל נחלה בארץ, וכן ראובן לא נטל רק בעבר הירדן
>   ושמעון נתקיים עליו אחלקם ביעקב כמוש"פ רמב"ן **ומהם היו בני חורין הרבה
>   ושרים אשר היו משעבדים את ישראל הנמכרים להם מהממשלה של פרעה, לכן צוה
>   השי"ת שבני ישראל גם פרעה יוציאו את בני ישראל מהשעבוד**

Essentially, the commandment told "to Klal Yisroel and Pharaoh to remove the Jews from slavery," refers not only to the Egyptian leader's requirement to send us out, but also to the tribes in power who had Jewish slaves. Specifically, Reuven, Shimon, and Levi who did not receive an inheritance in Eretz Yisroel proper had more independence in Egypt to have Jewish slaves (perhaps not having the land to hope for would have made being a slave too emotionally crushing). Although the Meshech Chochma does not suggest the Egyptians desired their position of power, it does note the higher positions these tribes had.

Answer (score 0):

The actual expression in the Midrash there is

> שֶׁהָיוּ פּוֹשְׁעִים בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁהָיָה לָהֶן פַּטְרוֹנִין מִן הַמִּצְרִיִּים וְהָיָה לָהֶן שָׁם עשֶׁר וְכָבוֹד
>
> there were wicked Jews *who had Egyptian patrons* and who had wealth
> and honor.

In other words, these Jews were indeed slaves or dependents of these Egyptian masters/patrons, but through their association with said masters, they could amass fortunes of their own. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery#Dependents:

> "Slavery" has also been used to refer to a legal state of dependency to somebody else. For example, in Persia, the situations and lives of such slaves could be better than those of common citizens."

So it may well have been the same in Egypt.

Comment: That's interesting! Thank you for the clarification. Wonder if that phenomena was recent with the plagues and all.